# Using c++11 lambda as accessor function in boost::python's add_property (get_signature fails with lambda)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, boost-python

I am trying to use c++11 lambdas as accessor functions in `boost::python`'s `add_property`, something along the following (the lambda is not strictly needed in this example, but will be needed for more complicated things happening inside the lambda, such as validation):

```
#include<boost/python.hpp>

struct A{
  A(): a(2){};
  int a;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(boost_python_lambda)
{
  boost::python::class_<A>("A")
    // .def_readonly("a",&A::a) // the classical way: works fine 
    .add_property("a",[](const A& a){return a.a;})
  ;
}
```

However, compiling with clang++ (ver. 3.2) and `-std=c++11` (the result is the same with g++ 4.7), I get this error:

```
/usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:442:66: error: no matching function for call to 'get_signature'
        return python::make_function(f, default_call_policies(), detail::get_signature(f, (T*)0));
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:422:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::python::class_<A,
      boost::python::detail::not_specified, boost::python::detail::not_specified,
      boost::python::detail::not_specified>::make_fn_impl<A, <lambda at boost_python_lambda.cpp:12:21> >' requested here
        return this->make_fn_impl(
                     ^
/usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:309:40: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::python::class_<A,
      boost::python::detail::not_specified, boost::python::detail::not_specified,
      boost::python::detail::not_specified>::make_getter<<lambda at boost_python_lambda.cpp:12:21> >' requested here
        base::add_property(name, this->make_getter(fget), docstr);
                                       ^
boost_python_lambda.cpp:12:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::python::class_<A,
      boost::python::detail::not_specified, boost::python::detail::not_specified,
      boost::python::detail::not_specified>::add_property<<lambda at boost_python_lambda.cpp:12:21> >' requested here
                .add_property("a",[](const A& a){return a.a;})
                 ^
```

I tried wrapping the lambda in `std::function<int(const A&)>(...)`, but that did not help with the argument deduction. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try `add_property<int(const A&)>("a",[](const A& a){return a.a;})`? It looks like `boost::python` cannot figure out the function signature.

Comment: I'm guessing that `get_signature` only checks for normal and member function pointers, not function objects' `operator()`.

Comment: This may not be the preferred solution, but you can perhaps use `+[](const A& a){return a.a;}` as a workaround -- or if that's not enough do it in tandem with `make_function`.

Comment: Lambdas are not special.

Answer (score 12):

Hopping in here two years later, Boost.Python indeed does not support wrapping function objects. But your lambda does not capture anything. As such, it can be explicitly convertible to a function pointer:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(boost_python_lambda)
{
  boost::python::class_<A>("A")
    // .def_readonly("a",&A::a) // the classical way: works fine 
    .add_property("a", +[](const A& a){return a.a;})
                       ↑↑↑
  ;
}
```

All you need is that `+`.

Comment: Thanks, but will not work for capturing lambdas. Which is where lambdas start to be really useful.

Comment: @eudoxos Yes, I know. But in this context, I'm not sure that you actually ever need to capture anything.

Comment: @Barry, could you please provide some reference to the docs where this syntax is described? I know that it compiles and works as expected but looks like a magic trick.

Comment: @AlexandraB. See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/2069064)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`make_function()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/make_function.html) function to create Python callable objects.  If Boost.Python cannot deduce the function object signature, then the signature must be explicitly provided as an [MPL front-extensible sequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/front-extensible-sequence.html).  For example, the lambda `[](const A& a) { return a.a; }` returns an `int` and accepts `const A&`, so one could use `boost::mpl::vector<int, const A&>()` for the signature.

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9e944897634eea9) using a pointer-to-data-member, casting non-capturing lambda to a function, and using a lambda/functor:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct A
{
  A(): a(2) {};
  int a;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<A>("A")
    // Expose pointer-to-data-member.
    .add_property("a1", &A::a)
    // Cast non-capturing lambda to a function.
    .add_property("a2", +[](const A& a) { return a.a; })
    // Make a python function from a functor.
    .add_property("a3", python::make_function(
        [](const A& a) { return a.a; },
        python::default_call_policies(),
        boost::mpl::vector<int, const A&>()))
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> a = example.A()
>>> assert(a.a1 == 2)
>>> assert(a.a2 == 2)
>>> assert(a.a3 == 2)
```

---

An alternative non-intrusive approach that is based on documented behavior is to write the lambda as a non-member function, then exposing it as the `fget` argument.  While not as succinct as lambda, it still allows for additional functionality, such as validation, to occur when accessing the member variable.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct A{
  A(): a(2){};
  int a;
};

int get_a(const A& a)
{
  // do validation
  // do more complicated things
  return a.a;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  boost::python::class_<A>("A")
    .add_property("a", &get_a);
  ;
}
```

Comment: I was not able to access the [link](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/c++-sig/2003-August/005184.html) (403), but [here](http://grokbase.com/t/python/cplusplus-sig/038e1vx5sy/c-sig-callable-object-instance-as-object-method) I see Dave Abrams proposing a method, but I can't get to make it compile. What you propose does not help really, my wrapper is generated using bunch of macros and it must all stay in one scope.

Comment: @eudoxos: Either add the capability to Boost.Python or work within the existing limitations.  One possibility to work around scope may be to assign the lambda to a global functor that is then invoked from within a non-member function.  It may be helpful to update the question to more closely match the problem being solved, rather than having it remain as only a compilation problem.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18648366/1053968) goes into more details about custom functors.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same problem when trying to use a lambda, and based on the solution for `std::function` above, I've added some more template magic, deducing the type of the `operator()` member function of the lambda (or functor):

https://gist.github.com/YannickJadoul/013d3adbf7f4e4abb4d5

And then things like this just work, when this header is included:

```
int *x = new int(0);
def("inc", [x] () { ++*x; });
def("get", [x] () { return *x; });
```

The only caveat that I know of, ftm, is that you should include this header befóre including `boost/python.hpp` (or any other Boost.Python header you are using that will need the `get_signature` function declarations):

```
#include "functor_signature.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you make the function type explicit by creating an std::function, then using the following piece of (C++11) code you can do it

```
namespace boost {
  namespace python {
    namespace detail {

      template <class T, class... Args>
      inline boost::mpl::vector<T, Args...> 
        get_signature(std::function<T(Args...)>, void* = 0)
      {
        return boost::mpl::vector<T, Args...>();
      }

    }
  }
}
```

example:

```
boost::python::class_<A>("A")
    // .def_readonly("a",&A::a) // the classical way: works fine 
    // .add_property("a", [](const A& a){return a.a; }) // ideal way, not possible since compiler cannot deduce return / arguments types
    .add_property("a", std::function<int(const A&)>([](const A& a){return a.a; }))
    ;
```

Comment: Will try, great. That should be proposed for inclusion in boost.

Comment: Trying your code, I am not able to make it work. The compiler (both clang and g++ with `--std=c++11`) say: `error: no matching function for call to 'get_signature'`, `return python::make_function(f, default_call_policies(), detail::get_signature(f, (T*)0));` and then `note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'RT (*)()' against 'std::function<int (const A &)>'` and so on. Any hint?

Comment: In Visual Studio it works from VS2013 and higher. Maybe your compiler does not support variadic templates? Which versions are you using?

Comment: g++ 4.8 and clang 3.4, both pretty recent and supporting variadic templates. Boost 1.54.  Strangely, the new template does not show up in the `note:` messages about candidate templates at all...

Comment: I had success with `.add_property("a",boost::python::detail::make_function_aux([](const A& a){return a.a;},boost::python::default_call_policies(),boost::mpl::vector<int,A>()));
` from [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2009-February/014263.html) but your solution looks much more elegant.

Comment: Adding the function to boost seems to work. I added it to boost/python/signature.hpp in the namespace boost::python::detail. You should also include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp> in that file.