# Exposing a C-style array data member to Python via Boost.Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I have a `struct` that contains a C-style array data member. I'd like to have this struct exposed to Python, and this data member be accessible as a list in Python.

```cpp
struct S
{
  char arr[4128];
};

void foo( S const * )
{}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( test )
{
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<S>( "S" )
    .def_readwrite( "arr", &S::arr )
    ;

  def( "foo", foo );
}
```

The code above fails to build

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [4128]' to 'char [4128]'
```

C-style arrays are not assignable, so the error makes sense. The code compiles if I change the data member to a plain `char` instead of an array.

I cannot replace the array with an `std::array` or some other container because the structure is being consumed by a C API. The only solution I can think of is to write a couple of wrappers and do the following

1. a `struct S1` that duplicates `S` except it'll have an `std::array` instead of a C-style array
2. A `foo_wrapper` that accepts a `S1 const *`, copies the contents over to an `S` instance and calls `foo`
3. Register a `to_python_converter` to convert the `std::array` to a Python list

This should work, and I'm not too concerned about the data copying at this point, but it'd be nice if I could avoid it and expose the array directly without having to jump through all these hoops.

So the question is, how can I expose that C-style array data member to Python as a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I arrived upon was to create a class `array_ref` that provides a non-owning view into a C-style array. Another class, `array_indexing_suite`, copy-pasted from `boost::python::vector_indexing_suite`, with all the member functions that mutate the size of the array modified from the original to throw errors, was then used to wrap `array_ref` to allow indexing operations from Python. The relevant code is below:

**`array_ref`**

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

/**
 * array_ref offers a non-const view into an array. The storage for the array is not owned by the
 * array_ref object, and it is the client's responsibility to ensure the backing store reamins
 * alive while the array_ref object is in use.
 *
 * @tparam T
 *      Type of elements in the array
 */
template<typename T>
class array_ref
{
public:
  /** Alias for the type of elements in the array */
  typedef T value_type;
  /** Alias for a pointer to value_type */
  typedef T *pointer;
  /** Alias for a constant pointer to value_type */
  typedef T const *const_pointer;
  /** Alias for a reference to value_type */
  typedef T& reference;
  /** Alias for a constant reference to value_type */
  typedef T const& const_reference;
  /** Alias for an iterator pointing at value_type objects */
  typedef T *iterator;
  /** Alias for a constant iterator pointing at value_type objects */
  typedef T const *const_iterator;
  /** Alias for a reverse iterator pointing at value_type objects */
  typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
  /** Alias for a constant reverse iterator pointing at value_type objects */
  typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
  /** Alias for an unsigned integral type used to represent size related values */
  typedef std::size_t size_type;
  /** Alias for a signed integral type used to represent result of difference computations */
  typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

  /** Default constructor */
  constexpr array_ref() noexcept = default;

  /**
   * Constructor that accepts a pointer to an array and the number of elements pointed at
   *
   * @param arr
   *    Pointer to array
   * @param length
   *    Number of elements pointed at
   */
  constexpr array_ref( pointer arr, size_type length ) noexcept
    : begin_(arr)
    , length_(length)
  {}

  /**
   * Constructor that accepts a reference to an array
   *
   * @tparam N
   *    Number of elements in the array
   */
  template<size_type N>
  constexpr array_ref( T (&arr)[N] ) noexcept
    : begin_(&arr[0])
    , length_(N)
  {}

  /**
   * Constructor taking a pair of pointers pointing to the first element and one past the last
   * element of the array, respectively.
   *
   * @param first
   *    Pointer to the first element of the array
   * @param last
   *    Pointer to one past the last element of the array
   */
  array_ref( pointer first, pointer last ) noexcept
    : begin_(first)
    , length_(static_cast<size_type>(std::distance(first, last)))
  {}

  /** Copy constructor */
  constexpr array_ref( array_ref const& ) noexcept = default;

  /** Copy assignment operator */
  array_ref& operator=( array_ref const& ) noexcept = default;

  /** Move constructor */
  constexpr array_ref( array_ref&& ) noexcept = default;

  /** Move assignment operator */
  array_ref& operator=( array_ref&& ) noexcept = default;

  /**
   * Returns an iterator to the first element of the array. If the array is empty, the
   * returned iterator will be equal to end().
   *
   * @return An iterator to the first element of the array
   */
  /*constexpr*/ iterator begin() noexcept
  {
    return begin_;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant iterator to the first element of the array. If the array is empty, the
   * returned iterator will be equal to end().
   *
   * @return A constant iterator to the first element of the array
   */
  constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept
  {
    return begin_;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant iterator to the first element of the array. If the array is empty, the
   * returned iterator will be equal to end().
   *
   * @return A constant iterator to the first element of the array
   */
  constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept
  {
    return begin_;
  }

  /**
   * Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the array.
   *
   * @return An iterator to the element following the last element of the array
   */
  /*constexpr*/ iterator end() noexcept
  {
    return begin() + size();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant iterator to the element following the last element of the array.
   *
   * @return A constant iterator to the element following the last element of the array
   */
  constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept
  {
    return begin() + size();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant iterator to the element following the last element of the array.
   *
   * @return A constant iterator to the element following the last element of the array
   */
  constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept
  {
    return cbegin() + size();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a reverse iterator to the first element of the reversed array. It corresponds to the
   * last element of the non-reversed array.
   *
   * @return A reverse iterator to the first element of the reversed array
   */
  reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept
  {
    return reverse_iterator( end() );
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant reverse iterator to the first element of the reversed array. It corresponds
   * to the last element of the non-reversed array.
   *
   * @return A constant reverse iterator to the first element of the reversed array
   */
  const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept
  {
    return const_reverse_iterator( cend() );
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant reverse iterator to the first element of the reversed array. It corresponds
   * to the last element of the non-reversed array.
   *
   * @return A constant reverse iterator to the first element of the reversed array
   */
  const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept
  {
    return const_reverse_iterator( cend() );
  }

  /**
   * Returns a reverse iterator to the element following the last element of the reversed array. It
   * corresponds to the element preceding the first element of the non-reversed array.
   *
   * @return A reverse iterator to the element following the last element of the reversed array
   */
  reverse_iterator rend() noexcept
  {
    return reverse_iterator( begin() );
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant reverse iterator to the element following the last element of the reversed
   * array. It corresponds to the element preceding the first element of the non-reversed array.
   *
   * @return A constant reverse iterator to the element following the last element of the reversed
   *         array
   */
  const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept
  {
    return const_reverse_iterator( cbegin() );
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant reverse iterator to the element following the last element of the reversed
   * array. It corresponds to the element preceding the first element of the non-reversed array.
   *
   * @return A constant reverse iterator to the element following the last element of the reversed
   *         array
   */
  const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept
  {
    return const_reverse_iterator( cbegin() );
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of elements in the array.
   *
   * @return The number of elements in the array
   */
  constexpr size_type size() const noexcept
  {
    return length_;
  }

  /**
   * Indicates whether the array has no elements
   *
   * @return true if the array has no elements, false otherwise
   */
  constexpr bool empty() const noexcept
  {
    return size() == 0;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a reference to the element at the specified location.
   *
   * @return A reference to the element at the specified location
   * @pre i < size()
   */
  /*constexpr*/ reference operator[]( size_type i )
  {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    return at( i );
#else
    return *(begin() + i);
#endif
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant reference to the element at the specified location.
   *
   * @return A constant reference to the element at the specified location
   * @pre i < size()
   */
  constexpr const_reference operator[]( size_type i ) const
  {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    return at( i );
#else
    return *(begin() + i);
#endif
  }

  /**
   * Returns a reference to the element at the specified location, with bounds checking.
   *
   * @return A reference to the element at the specified location
   * @throw std::out_of_range if the specified index is not within the range of the array
   */
  /*constexpr*/ reference at( size_type i )
  {
    if( i >= size() ) {
      throw std::out_of_range( "index out of range" );
    }
    return *(begin() + i);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant reference to the element at the specified location, with bounds checking.
   *
   * @return A constant reference to the element at the specified location
   * @throw std::out_of_range if the specified index is not within the range of the array
   */
  /*constexpr*/ const_reference at( size_type i ) const
  {
    if( i >= size() ) {
      throw std::out_of_range( "index out of range" );
    }
    return *(begin() + i);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a reference to the first element of the array
   *
   * @return A reference to the first element of the array
   * @pre empty() == false
   */
  /*constexpr*/ reference front() noexcept
  {
    return *begin();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a reference to the first element of the array
   *
   * @return A reference to the first element of the array
   * @pre empty() == false
   */
  constexpr const_reference front() const noexcept
  {
    return *begin();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a reference to the last element of the array
   *
   * @return A reference to the last element of the array
   * @pre empty() == false
   */
  /*constexpr*/ reference back() noexcept
  {
    return *(end() - 1);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant reference to the last element of the array
   *
   * @return A constant reference to the last element of the array
   * @pre empty() == false
   */
  constexpr const_reference back() const noexcept
  {
    return *(end() - 1);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a pointer to the address of the first element of the array
   *
   * @return A pointer to the address of the first element of the array
   */
  /*constexpr*/ pointer data() noexcept
  {
    return begin();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a constant pointer to the address of the first element of the array
   *
   * @return A constant pointer to the address of the first element of the array
   */
  constexpr const_pointer data() const noexcept
  {
    return begin();
  }

  /**
   * Resets the operand back to its default constructed state
   *
   * @post empty() == true
   */
  void clear() noexcept
  {
    begin_ = nullptr;
    length_ = 0;
  }

private:
  /** Pointer to the first element of the referenced array */
  pointer begin_ = nullptr;
  /** Number of elements in the referenced array */
  size_type length_ = size_type();
};
```

**`array_indexing_suite`**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/indexing_suite.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

// Forward declaration
template<
  typename Array,
  bool NoProxy,
  typename DerivedPolicies>
class array_indexing_suite;


namespace detail {

template<typename Array, bool NoProxy>
struct final_array_derived_policies
: array_indexing_suite<Array, NoProxy, final_array_derived_policies<Array, NoProxy>>
{};

}   /* namespace detail */


template<
  typename Array,
  bool NoProxy = std::is_arithmetic<typename Array::value_type>::value,
  typename DerivedPolicies = detail::final_array_derived_policies<Array, NoProxy>
>
class array_indexing_suite
  : public boost::python::indexing_suite<Array,
                                         DerivedPolicies,
                                         NoProxy>
{
public:
  typedef typename Array::value_type data_type;
  typedef typename Array::value_type key_type;
  typedef typename Array::size_type index_type;
  typedef typename Array::size_type size_type;
  typedef typename Array::difference_type difference_type;

  static data_type& get_item( Array& arr, index_type i )
  {
    return arr[i];
  }

  static void set_item( Array& arr, index_type i, data_type const& v )
  {
      arr[i] = v;
  }

  static void delete_item( Array& /*arr*/, index_type /*i*/ )
  {
    ::PyErr_SetString( ::PyExc_TypeError, "Cannot delete array item" );
    boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
  }

  static size_type size( Array& arr )
  {
    return arr.size();
  }

  static bool contains( Array& arr, key_type const& key )
  {
    return std::find( arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), key ) != arr.cend();
  }

  static index_type get_min_index( Array& )
  {
    return 0;
  }

  static index_type get_max_index( Array& arr )
  {
    return arr.size();
  }

  static bool compare_index( Array&, index_type a, index_type b )
  {
    return a < b;
  }

  static index_type convert_index( Array& arr, PyObject *i_ )
  {
    boost::python::extract<long> i(i_);
    if( i.check() ) {
      long index = i();

      if( index < 0 ) {
        index += static_cast<decltype(index)>(DerivedPolicies::size( arr ));
      }

      if( ( index >= long(arr.size()) ) || ( index < 0 ) ) {
        ::PyErr_SetString( ::PyExc_IndexError, "Index out of range" );
        boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
      }
      return index;
    }

    ::PyErr_SetString( ::PyExc_TypeError, "Invalid index type" );
    boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
    return index_type();
  }

  static boost::python::object get_slice( Array& arr, index_type from, index_type to )
  {
      if( from > to ) {
        return boost::python::object( Array() );
      }
      return boost::python::object( Array( arr.begin() + from, arr.begin() + to ) );
  }

  static void set_slice( Array& arr, index_type from, index_type to, data_type const& v )
  {
    if( from > to ) {
      return;

    } else if( to > arr.size() ) {
      ::PyErr_SetString( ::PyExc_IndexError, "Index out of range" );
      boost::python::throw_error_already_set();

    } else {
      std::fill( arr.begin() + from, arr.begin() + to, v );

    }
  }

  template<typename Iter>
  static void set_slice( Array& arr, index_type from, index_type to, Iter first, Iter last )
  {
    auto num_items = std::distance( first, last );

    if( ( from + num_items ) > arr.size() ) {
      ::PyErr_SetString( ::PyExc_IndexError, "Index out of range" );
      boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
      return;
    }

    if( from > to ) {
      std::copy( first, last, arr.begin() + from );

    } else {
      if( static_cast<decltype(num_items)>( to - from ) != num_items ) {
        ::PyErr_SetString( ::PyExc_TypeError, "Array length is immutable" );
        boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
        return;

      }

      std::copy( first, last, arr.begin() + from );
    }
  }

  static void delete_slice( Array& /*arr*/, index_type /*from*/, index_type /*to*/ )
  {
    ::PyErr_SetString( ::PyExc_TypeError, "Cannot delete array item(s)" );
    boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
  }
};
```

Finally, the bits required to create the bindings.

```
struct foo
{
    char data[100];
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( foo_module )
{
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<array_ref<unsigned char>>( "uchar_array" )
    .def( array_indexing_suite<array_ref<unsigned char>>() )
    ;

  class_<foo>( "foo", "Foo's description" )
    .add_property( "data",
                   /* getter that returns an array_ref view into the array */
                   static_cast<array_ref<unsigned char>(*)( foo * )>(
                      []( foo *obj ) {
                        return array_ref<unsigned char>( obj->data );
                      }),
                     "Array of data bytes" )
    ;
}
```

Comment: please see if upstream will accept your helpful snippet

Comment: also noting from Barry's post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845547/using-c11-lambda-as-accessor-function-in-boostpythons-add-property-get-sig you can clean up that awful lambda property cast with a + infront of the lambda

Comment: Can it be adopted to expose `char *x[]` arguments?

Comment: @nicolai You have a C++ function that takes a `char *[]` parameter? I would write a thin wrapper, see `invite` [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/ExportingClasses) that takes a list of lists from Python, and converts it to `char *x[]` before calling the C++ function.

Comment: @Praetorian >You have a C++ function that takes a char *[] parameter?
Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

As you've seen, Boost.Python unfortunately doesn't provide automatic converters for C arrays, and even the STL container wrappers it provides aren't how I'd recommend approaching this (at least if your real problem is similar to your example one in terms of how large the array is, and if you know you want to expose it as a true Python tuple).

I'd recommend writing a function that converts the C array into a Python tuple, using either the Python C-API directly, or its boost::python wrappers, and then exposing the data member via a property.  While you could avoid data copying by using a NumPy array instead of a tuple, for small arrays that's not worth the effort.

For example:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;

bp::tuple wrap_arr(S const * s) {
    bp::list a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        a.append(s->arr[i]);
    }
    return bp::tuple(a);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( test ) {
  bp::class_<S>( "S" )
     .add_property("arr", wrap_arr)
  ;
}
```

Comment: +1 I'd forgotten `add_property` accepted getters and setters. Also, I actually need a list, not a tuple, since I want it to be modifiable on the python side. Your solution is better than what I was thinking of, especially since I can write the getter and setter as lambdas and have it be succinct. But the array isn't really 10 chars, it's 4128. I'll update the question also with that information; I shouldn't have led people to believe the copy is extremely trivial (even though I haven't had a chance to prove copying is prohibitive for me yet)

Comment: If you need to be able to modify the elements in-place, but you don't need to be able to add or remove elements, then you almost certainly need to expose this via something like a NumPy array.  Even a Python list will force you to copy your data, so modifications won't propagate back to C++.  So either you use NumPy, or you write and wrap a list-like proxy class that modifies your C array under-the-hood...and that's basically what a NumPy array is.

Comment: In-place modification is exactly what I want to have happen. Do you happen to know of a NumPy / Boost.Python example I could look at?

Comment: If you're not averse to adding another dependency, you may want to check out https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy, a library I've written to make accessing the NumPy C-API within Boost.Python a little friendlier.  The 'gaussian' example in that package does almost exactly what you want.  If adding another dependency isn't an option, it should be pretty straightforward to follow the code there to see the NumPy C-API calls underneath.

Comment: I found that library yesterday while digging through some other answers of yours :-). I went another route and created an `array_ref` class that offers a non-const view into an array. The getter for `add_property` wraps the array in an `array_ref`, and then another class, `array_indexing_suite` (copied from Boost's `vector_indexing_suite`), handles the Python interop.