# Boost.Python: Wrap functions to release the GIL

Tags: c++, python, function, boost, boost-python

I am currently working with Boost.Python and would like some help to solve a tricky problem.

**Context**

When a C++ method/function is exposed to Python, it needs to release the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) to let other threads use the interpreter. This way, when the python code calls a C++ function, the interpreter can be used by other threads.
For now, each C++ function looks like this:

```
// module.cpp
int myfunction(std::string question)
{
    ReleaseGIL unlockGIL;
    return 42;
}
```

To pass it to boost python, I do:

```
// python_exposure.cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonModule)
{
    def("myfunction", &myfunction);
}
```

**Problem**

This scheme works fine, however it implies that `module.cpp` depends on `Boost.Python` for no good reason. Ideally, only `python_exposure.cpp` should depend on `Boost.Python`.

**Solution?**

My idea was to play with `Boost.Function` to wrap the function calls like this:

```
// python_exposure.cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonModule)
{
    def("myfunction", wrap(&myfunction));
}
```

Here `wrap` would be in charge of unlocking the GIL during the call to `myfunction`. The problem with this method is that `wrap` needs to have the same signature as `myfunction` which would pretty much mean re-implementing `Boost.Function`...

I would be very thankful if someone had any suggestion to this problem.

Comment: I found an excellent answer from e.tadeu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135457/how-to-write-a-wrapper-over-functions-and-member-functions-that-executes-some-co?rq=1

Comment: Although it _should_ be safe, exposing functors as methods is not [officially supported](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/todo.html#wrapping-function-objects).  The supported approach would be to expose a non-member function that delegates to the member-function.

Comment: This is a very interesting point. I wonder what is lacking in their implementation.

Comment: I too found myself interested, so decided to dig through the code.  I have included my findings in the answer below, as well as a potentially reusable solution to your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exposing functors as methods is not [officially supported](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/todo.html#wrapping-function-objects). The supported approach would be to expose a non-member function that delegates to the member-function.  However, this can result in a large amount of boilerplate code.

As best as I can tell, Boost.Python's implementation does not explicitly preclude functors, as it allows for instances of `python::object` to be exposed as a method.  However, Boost.Python does place some requirements on the type of object being exposed as a method:

- The functor is CopyConstructible.
- The functor is callable.  I.e. instance `o` can be called `o(a1, a2, a3)`.
- The call signature must be available as meta-data during runtime.  Boost.Python calls the `boost::python::detail::get_signature()` function to obtain this meta-data.  The meta-data is used internally to setup proper invocation, as well as for dispatching from Python to C++.

The latter requirement is where it gets complex.  For some reason that is not immediately clear to me, Boost.Python invokes `get_signature()` through a qualified-id, preventing argument dependent lookup.  Therefore, all candidates for `get_signature()` must be declared before the calling template's definition context.  For example, the only overloads for `get_signature()` that are considered are those declared before the definition of templates that invoke it, such as `class_`, `def()`, and `make_function()`.  To account for this behavior, when enabling a functor in Boost.Python, one must provide a `get_signature()` overload prior to including Boost.Python or explicitly provide a meta-sequence representing the signature to `make_function()`.

---

Lets work through some examples of enabling functor support, as well as providing functors that support guards.  I have opted to not use C++11 features.  As such, there will be some boilerplate code that could be reduced with variadic templates.  Additionally, all of the examples will use the same model that provides two non-member functions and a `spam` class that has two member-functions:

```cpp
/// @brief Mockup class with member functions.
class spam
{
public:
  void action()
  {
    std::cout << "spam::action()"  << std::endl;
  }

  int times_two(int x)
  {
    std::cout << "spam::times_two()" << std::endl;
    return 2 * x;
  }
};

// Mockup non-member functions.
void action()
{
  std::cout << "action()"  << std::endl;
}

int times_two(int x)
{
  std::cout << "times_two()" << std::endl;
  return 2 * x;
}
```

#### Enabling `boost::function`

When using the [preferred syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#idp59212272) for Boost.Function, decomposing the signature into meta-data that meets Boost.Python requirements can be done with [Boost.FunctionTypes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/decomposition.html).  Here is a complete example enabling `boost::function` functors to be exposed as a Boost.Python method:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/components.hpp>

namespace boost  {
namespace python {
namespace detail {
// get_signature overloads must be declared before including
// boost/python.hpp.  The declaration must be visible at the
// point of definition of various Boost.Python templates during
// the first phase of two phase lookup.  Boost.Python invokes the
// get_signature function via qualified-id, thus ADL is disabled.

/// @brief Get the signature of a boost::function.
template <typename Signature>
inline typename boost::function_types::components<Signature>::type
get_signature(boost::function<Signature>&, void* = 0)
{
  return typename boost::function_types::components<Signature>::type();
}

} // namespace detail
} // namespace python
} // namespace boost

#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup class with member functions.
class spam
{
public:
  void action()
  {
    std::cout << "spam::action()"  << std::endl;
  }

  int times_two(int x)
  {
    std::cout << "spam::times_two()" << std::endl;
    return 2 * x;
  }
};

// Mockup non-member functions.
void action()
{
  std::cout << "action()"  << std::endl;
}

int times_two(int x)
{
  std::cout << "times_two()" << std::endl;
  return 2 * x;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose class and member-function.
  python::class_<spam>("Spam")
    .def("action",  &spam::action)
    .def("times_two", boost::function<int(spam&, int)>(
        &spam::times_two))
    ;

  // Expose non-member function.
  python::def("action",  &action);
  python::def("times_two", boost::function<int()>(
      boost::bind(&times_two, 21)));
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> spam.action()
spam::action()
>>> spam.times_two(5)
spam::times_two()
10
>>> example.action()
action()
>>> example.times_two()
times_two()
42
```

When providing a functor that will invoke a member-function, the provided signature needs to be the non-member function equivalent.  In this case, `int(spam::*)(int)` becomes `int(spam&, int)`.

```cpp
// ...
  .def("times_two", boost::function<int(spam&, int)>(
        &spam::times_two))
  ;
```

Also, arguments can be bound to the functors with [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/bind/bind.html).  For example, calling `example.times_two()` does not have to provide an argument, as `21` is already bound to the functor.

```cpp
python::def("times_two", boost::function<int()>(
    boost::bind(&times_two, 21)));
```

#### Custom functor with guards

Expanding upon the above example, one can enable custom functor types to be used with Boost.Python.  Lets create a functor, called `guarded_function`, that will use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), only invoking the wrapped function during the RAII object's lifetime.

```
/// @brief Functor that will invoke a function while holding a guard.
///        Upon returning from the function, the guard is released.
template <typename Signature,
          typename Guard>
class guarded_function
{
public:

  typedef typename boost::function_types::result_type<Signature>::type
      result_type;

  template <typename Fn>
  guarded_function(Fn fn)
    : fn_(fn)
  {}

  result_type operator()()
  {
    Guard g;
    return fn_();
  }

  // ... overloads for operator()

private:
  boost::function<Signature> fn_;
};
```

The `guarded_function` provides similar semantics to the Python [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement.  Thus, to keep with the Boost.Python API name choices, a `with()` C++ function will provide a way to create functors.

```
/// @brief Create a callable object with guards.
template <typename Guard,
          typename Fn>
boost::python::object
with(Fn fn)
{
   return boost::python::make_function(
     guarded_function<Guard, Fn>(fn), ...);
}
```

This allows for functions to be exposed which will run with a guard in a non-intrusive manner:

```
class no_gil; // Guard

// ...
  .def("times_two", with<no_gil>(&spam::times_two))
  ;
```

Additionally, the `with()` function provides the ability to deduce the function signatures, allowing the meta-data signature to be explicitly provided to Boost.Python rather than having to overload `boost::python::detail::get_signature()`.

Here is the complete example, using two RAII types:

- `no_gil`: Releases GIL in constructor, and reacquires GIL in destructor.
- `echo_guard`: Prints in constructor and destructor.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/components.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/function_type.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/result_type.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

namespace detail {

/// @brief Functor that will invoke a function while holding a guard.
///        Upon returning from the function, the guard is released.
template <typename Signature,
          typename Guard>
class guarded_function
{
public:

  typedef typename boost::function_types::result_type<Signature>::type
      result_type;

  template <typename Fn>
  guarded_function(Fn fn)
    : fn_(fn)
  {}

  result_type operator()()
  {
    Guard g;
    return fn_();
  }

  template <typename A1>
  result_type operator()(A1 a1)
  {
    Guard g;
    return fn_(a1);
  }

  template <typename A1, typename A2>
  result_type operator()(A1 a1, A2 a2)
  {
    Guard g;
    return fn_(a1, a2);
  }

private:
  boost::function<Signature> fn_;
};

/// @brief Provides signature type.
template <typename Signature>
struct mpl_signature
{
  typedef typename boost::function_types::components<Signature>::type type;
};

// Support boost::function.
template <typename Signature>
struct mpl_signature<boost::function<Signature> >:
  public mpl_signature<Signature>
{};

/// @brief Create a callable object with guards.
template <typename Guard,
          typename Fn,
          typename Policy>
boost::python::object with_aux(Fn fn, const Policy& policy)
{
  // Obtain the components of the Fn.  This will decompose non-member
  // and member functions into an mpl sequence.
  //   R (*)(A1)    => R, A1
  //   R (C::*)(A1) => R, C*, A1
  typedef typename mpl_signature<Fn>::type mpl_signature_type;

  // Synthesize the components into a function type.  This process
  // causes member functions to require the instance argument.
  // This is necessary because member functions will be explicitly
  // provided the 'self' argument.
  //   R, A1     => R (*)(A1)
  //   R, C*, A1 => R (*)(C*, A1)
  typedef typename boost::function_types::function_type<
      mpl_signature_type>::type signature_type;

  // Create a callable boost::python::object that delegates to the
  // guarded_function.
  return boost::python::make_function(
    guarded_function<signature_type, Guard>(fn),
    policy, mpl_signature_type());
}

} // namespace detail

/// @brief Create a callable object with guards.
template <typename Guard,
          typename Fn,
          typename Policy>
boost::python::object with(const Fn& fn, const Policy& policy)
{
  return detail::with_aux<Guard>(fn, policy);
}

/// @brief Create a callable object with guards.
template <typename Guard,
          typename Fn>
boost::python::object with(const Fn& fn)
{
  return with<Guard>(fn, boost::python::default_call_policies());
}

/// @brief Mockup class with member functions.
class spam
{
public:
  void action()
  {
    std::cout << "spam::action()"  << std::endl;
  }

  int times_two(int x)
  {
    std::cout << "spam::times_two()" << std::endl;
    return 2 * x;
  }
};

// Mockup non-member functions.
void action()
{
  std::cout << "action()"  << std::endl;
}

int times_two(int x)
{
  std::cout << "times_two()" << std::endl;
  return 2 * x;
}

/// @brief Guard that will unlock the GIL upon construction, and
///        reacquire it upon destruction.
struct no_gil
{
public:
  no_gil()  { state_ = PyEval_SaveThread(); 
              std::cout << "no_gil()" << std::endl; }
  ~no_gil() { std::cout << "~no_gil()" << std::endl;
              PyEval_RestoreThread(state_); }
private:
  PyThreadState* state_;
};

/// @brief Guard that prints to std::cout.
struct echo_guard 
{
  echo_guard()  { std::cout << "echo_guard()" << std::endl;  }
  ~echo_guard() { std::cout << "~echo_guard()" << std::endl; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose class and member-function.
  python::class_<spam>("Spam")
    .def("action", &spam::action)
    .def("times_two", with<no_gil>(&spam::times_two))
    ;

  // Expose non-member function.
  python::def("action", &action);
  python::def("times_two", with<boost::tuple<no_gil, echo_guard> >(
      &times_two));
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> spam.action()
spam::action()
>>> spam.times_two(5)
no_gil()
spam::times_two()
~no_gil()
10
>>> example.action()
action()
>>> example.times_two(21)
no_gil()
echo_guard()
times_two()
~echo_guard()
~no_gil()
42
```

Notice how multiple guards can be provided by using a container type, such as `boost::tuple`:

```cpp
  python::def("times_two", with<boost::tuple<no_gil, echo_guard> >(
      &times_two));
```

When invoked in Python, `example.times_two(21)` produces the following output:

```
no_gil()
echo_guard()
times_two()
~echo_guard()
~no_gil()
42
```

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate this perfect and clear explanation, as well as the fact that you didn't use C++11 in it (nothing against it of course). This solution is **AMAZING**! It is clean and generic, thank you so much! It solves my problem perfectly and I am sure I will reuse that code a couple times. Guards should be at the door, not inside :)

Comment: Hi Tanner, I encounter this wrong signature issue when using your code. I posted my solution to this problem below. Maybe I missed something in your explanation. Anyway, thanks again for your answer, it helped me immensely!

Answer (score 2):

If someone is interested, I had a small issue with **Tanner Sansbury**'s code when using his final working example. For some reason, I still had the problem he mentioned about having the wrong signature in the final generated `boost::function`:

```
// example for spam::times_two:
//   correct signature (manual)
int (spam::*, int)
//   wrong signature (generated in the `guarded_function` wrapper)
int (spam&, int)
```

even when overloading `boost::python::detail::get_signature()`. The responsible for this was `boost::function_types::components`; it has a default template parameter `ClassTranform = add_reference<_>` which creates this class reference. To fix this, I simply changed the `mpl_signature` struct as follow:

```
// other includes
# include <boost/type_traits/add_pointer.hpp>
# include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>

template <typename Signature> struct mpl_signature
{
  typedef typename boost::function_types::components<Signature,
                boost::add_pointer<boost::mpl::placeholders::_> >::type type;
};

template <typename Signature> struct mpl_signature<boost::function<Signature> >
{
  typedef typename boost::function_types::components<Signature>::type type;
};
```

And now everything works like a charm.

If someone can confirm this is indeed the right fix, I'd be interested :)