# No python class registered for C++ class function pointer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I am trying to write a wrapper `Python` class for `pika` in `C++`. In `pika`, when messages are consumed, there is a function called `callback(ch, method, properties, body)`. To consume messages, you have to put the `callback` function inside `basic_consume` method. In my case, my `callback` function resides inside `C++` code because `C++` handles all the necessary things, then transfer the callback back to the Consumer class. I would like to do every logic inside `C++` file and leave the `Python class` alone in this case.

`C++:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;


// boost function
void function(object *ch, object *method, object *properties, string body) {
    cout << "INSIDE FUNC" << body << endl;
}       

int main() {
    Py_Initialize(); 
    try {
        boost::function<void(object*, object*, object*, string)> myfunc;
        myfunc = boost::bind(function, _1, _2, _3, _4);
        object a = import("consumer");
        object b = a.attr("A");
        object c = b.attr("callback")(boost::ref(myfunc));
    }
    catch(error_already_set const &) {
        PyErr_Print();
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

`Python: consumer.py`

```
import pika 

class A:
    def __init__(self): 
        cppcallback = None
        self.connect()

    def connect(): 
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost"))
        channel = connection.channel()

    def callback(cppdosomething): 
        print "CALLED"
        cppcallback = cppdosomething 
        self.start_consume()

    def start_consume(self): 
        channel.basic_consume(cppcallback, queue="hello_world")
        channel.start_consuming()
```

But right now, I am getting this error.

> TypeError: No Python class registered for C++ class boost::function<void (boost::python::api::object*, boost::python::api::object*, boost::python::api::object*, std::string)>

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you trim your python sample, and remove the dependency on pika, since it's not really related to the fundamental question. Then remove those two tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Commentary

There are several unrelated issues with your example code:

- `object b = a.attr("A");` -- This gets the class type. You need to run the constructor to create an instance of `A`. That means `a.attr("A")();`.
- In the Python script, `cppcallback` is a local variable in `__init__` and `callback` functions. In `start_consume` it's undefined. This should be a member variable, as in `self.cppcallback`.
- Having pointers to `object` as parameters to your callback handler is debatable. I think it's fine to pass them by value.

## Solution

### Python Script

I wrote a simplified script that mimics what you've got:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handler = None

    def callback(self, handler):
        self.handler = handler
        self.do_something()

    def do_something(self):
        self.handler(1,2,3,"foo")
```

### Using Plain Functions

This approach is quite straightforward.

First create a callable [`object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/object_wrappers/boost_python_object_hpp.html#object_wrappers.boost_python_object_hpp.class_object) using [`make_function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/boost_python_make_function_hpp.html).

Then import the Python `test_module` from our script, construct and instance of `A` and call it's `callback` member passing it our callable object as parameter.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::python;

void callback_handler(bp::object ch
    , bp::object method
    , bp::object properties
    , std::string const& body)
{
    std::cout << "in handler: " << body << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    try {
        bp::object h = bp::make_function(callback_handler);

        bp::object a = bp::import("test_module");
        bp::object b = a.attr("A")(); // Construct instance of A

        b.attr("callback")(h);
    } catch (bp::error_already_set const &) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
>example_1.exe
in handler: foo
```

### Using `boost::function`

Using `boost::function` object for the callback handler is a little trickier, since `boost::function` is not supported by `boost::python` by default. Thus, we first need to enable support for `boost::function`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18648366/3962537) by [Tanner Sansbury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053968/tanner-sansbury).

**NB**: This snippet needs to come before including `boost/python.hpp`!

```
// ============================================================================
// Enable support for boost::function
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18648366/3962537
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/components.hpp>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace boost { namespace python { namespace detail {
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// get_signature overloads must be declared before including
// boost/python.hpp.  The declaration must be visible at the
// point of definition of various Boost.Python templates during
// the first phase of two phase lookup.  Boost.Python invokes the
// get_signature function via qualified-id, thus ADL is disabled.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// @brief Get the signature of a boost::function.
template <typename Signature>
inline typename boost::function_types::components<Signature>::type
get_signature(boost::function<Signature>&, void* = 0)
{
    return typename boost::function_types::components<Signature>::type();
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
}}} // namespace boost::python::detail
// ============================================================================
```

The rest is very similar to the first scenario.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::python;

void callback_handler(bp::object ch
    , bp::object method
    , bp::object properties
    , std::string const& body
    , std::string const& extra)
{
    std::cout << "in handler: " << body << extra << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    try {
        typedef boost::function<void(bp::object, bp::object, bp::object, std::string)> handler_fn;
        handler_fn my_handler(boost::bind(callback_handler, _1, _2, _3, _4, " bar"));
        bp::object h = bp::make_function(my_handler);

        bp::object a = bp::import("test_module");
        bp::object b = a.attr("A")();

        b.attr("callback")(h);
    } catch (bp::error_already_set const &) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
>example_2.exe
in handler: foo bar
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks so much.